# Cannot switch user after upgrade from Azure Devops Server 2019 to 2020.1.2

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server-2020

After the upgrade from Azure DevOps Server 2019 to 2020.1.2, it is impossible to switch users. Currently, this is being tested on a test ADS server

Original version:
Edition: Azure DevOps Server 2019
Product Version: 17.153.29522.3 (AzureDevOps2019 Update 1.1)

The upgrade is done via azuredevops2020.1.2.iso
Edition: Azure DevOps Server 2020
Product Version: 18.181.32404.7 (AzureDevOps2020 Update 1.2)

First logon works without problem and I have access to Azure DevOps Server 2020.
When I do "Sign in as ...", I get the popup screen to enter new (or the same) credentials.
I enter the correct credentials with enough permissions +  click enter and the popup screen returns empty (every time). When I click cancel on the popup, I get the error "TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required."

If I go back to my URL http:/// after the failure, I can log in again with any user.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

I tried the following:
The first attempt was to directly install azuredevops2020.1.2.iso
Second attempt I
on the first attempt was to directly install azuredevops2020.1.2.iso
on the second attempt I
Installed azuredevopsserver2020.0.1.iso
Installed devops2020.0.1patch9.exe
(this was the patch that would resolve the issue, but the test still failed)
Installed azuredevops2020.1.2.iso